# Problem with json parsing in iphone application

Tags: iphone, json, ipad

My application is crashing whenever i click on submit button.

2011-08-09 19:41:29.590 ItcHotel[3888:207] reached here in didReceiveData
2011-08-09 19:41:29.593 ItcHotel[3888:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]'
*** Call stack at first throw:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps sharing some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You are attempting to insert `nil` into the first position of the array (index 0). `NSArray` objects can not contain `nil` values. The C array passed as parameter to `initWithObjects:count:` must contain `nil` values.

Add some code if you want more detail.